# TransactionScope doesn't work on server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, oracle

I'm using TransactionScope so I can rollback the alterations I've made in case an exception is thrown

My code is kinda like this:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope()) {

    // Get some Datatables from the database
    // Do stuff with the data
    // Update tables

    scope.Complete();

}
```

If I run it on my computer it works perfectly 100% of the time, but when I run it from my company's server it always returns me this error:

```
The Promote Method Returned An Invalid Value For The Distributed Transaction
```

It happens the second time I try to get a datatable from the database inside the scope.

I'm not using Azure nor multiple databases.
We're using Oracle 11g.

Comment: What Oracle client are you using to connect? Is it the same in both environments?

Comment: Both are using 11.2.0.1.0